# Not getting output for simple java program to find greatest prime factor

Tags: java

```
class LargestPrimeFactor{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        long p=0L;
        long n=600851475143L;
        for(long i=2L;i<(n/2);i++){
            if((BigInteger.valueOf(i)).isProbablePrime(1)){
                if(n%i==0){
                    p=i;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

It's [problem 3 from Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3). I compiled it and no errors showed up. But am not getting any output. Whats the reason?

Comment: Does it terminate? It might just take it some time to do all those calculations.

Comment: `long n = 600851475143 L;` - are you sure that this compiled and no errors showed up...?

Comment: @Jaroslaw Pawlak I think you mean 600851475143L, 'cos adding that one space before will give the same error, "Integer number too large".

Answer (score 1):

It is working (just add a print method inside the loop to check i for example).
You are currently using the Brute-Force method:
http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-problem-3/

If you visit the link the guy tells you an alternative solution for it.

The problem I see without having much knowledge about this is
that the operations you currently do are way too many.
You got the value "`600851475143`" stored in a long datatype and you try to
reach the half (`300425737571,5`) using the int i (counter in your for-loop).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE

This tells us: "A constant holding the maximum value an int can have,

```
2^(31)-1." = 2147483647
```

This is just `0,00715 (0,7%)` of what you actually need.
So this leads us to an "Overflow".

Think of using the alternative method (first link)
and change the counter of your for-loop to type "long".

Answer (score 0):

int maximum value is 2147483647 which is smaller than 600851475143/2

when index i reaches max value it will wrap around and start with negative number (-2147483648)

you should make your index i a long value

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

The `int` data type can store values upto 2,147,483,647. To store numbers beyond that, use `long`.

```
long n = 600851475143L;
```

Not `600851475143 L`, as that one space before `L` causes the system to not register it.

Also, `int i` in the for loop should be `long i`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop on the second for iteration you can only see it when you add logging before the end of the loop. It's not because it's not printing the value, when you stare at the console the iterator is still circling through 6857.

Try running the code with extra logging below.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int p = 0;
    long n = 600851475143L;
    for (int i = 2; i < (n / 2); i++) {
        if ((BigInteger.valueOf(i)).isProbablePrime(1)) {
            if (BigInteger.valueOf(n % i).compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(0)) == 0) {
                p = i;
                System.out.println("Check == true Iteration"+p);
            }
            System.err.println("Second iterator"+p);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Final Value of P: "+p);
}
```

Comment: it should be `long i` in the for loop.

Comment: This doesn't solve it, the iterations are just either infinite or too many for this algorithm to be efficient in any sense. I waited 60second and still didn't see the output.

Comment: Could you pls elaborate. I have no idea what logging is... And how is it an infinite loop?